# CMFCRibbonColorComboBox set background color for selected Item

Tags: mfc, ribbon-control

How to derive my class `CMFCRibbonColorComboBox` from `CMFCRibbonComboBox`
and override `OnDrawDropListItem`?

How I can set background color for selected item after selection.

```
BOOL CMFCRibbonColorComboBox::OnDrawDropListItem(CDC* pDC, int nIndex, CMFCToolBarMenuButton* pItem, BOOL bHighlight)
{
    ASSERT_VALID(this);
    CRect rc = pItem->Rect();
    LPCTSTR lpszText = GetItem(nIndex);
    if (lpszText == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    CString strText = lpszText;
    pDC->DrawText(strText, rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CMFCRibbonComboBox` class is derived from `CMFCRibbonEdit` which is derived from `CMFCRibbonButton`. As far as I can tell you need to override `virtual COLORREF CMFCRibbonButton::OnFillBackground(CDC* pDC)`

Comment: OnFillBackground is not getting called. Can you try?

Comment: I'll look into it when I have time. Try setting breakpoint in OnDraw and see what it does step by step.